# NSURLSessionDataTask returning incorrect result

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

I have used following code for Posting request through `NSURLSession`, but it is returning incorrect result. but if I check it with POSTMAN with same parameters and url then it's working fine. Please help.

```
// URL of the endpoint we're going to contact.
NSURL *url = url;

// Create a simple dictionary with numbers.
NSDictionary *param = @{@"key1": @"value1"};

NSError *error = nil;
// Convert the dictionary into JSON data.
NSData *JSONData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:param
                                                   options:kNilOptions error:&error];

// Create a POST request with our JSON as a request body.
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
request.HTTPBody = JSONData;

// Create a task.
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                                             completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                                                                 NSURLResponse *response,
                                                                                 NSError *error)
                              {
                                  if (!error)
                                  {
                                      if (data) {
                                          json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
                                          success(json);

                                      }
                                      else {
                                          failure(error);
                                          NSLog(@"******************* error in sendRequestToServer");
                                      }
                                      //NSLog(@"Status code: %i", ((NSHTTPURLResponse *)response).statusCode);
                                  }
                                  else {
                                      failure(error);
                                      NSLog(@"******************* error in sendRequestToServer");
                                  }
                              }];

// Start the task.
[task resume];
```

Comment: What incorrect result? How do you know it's that different? Do you go into an error case ?

Comment: it's not giving any error. but the result is different from POSTMAN

Comment: How much different? Wrong result ?

Comment: yes, like it's giving "sorry user does not exist", but in postman it's giving data for that user, notOK result coming from web

Comment: I have also tried [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request
                                                                       fromData:data completionHandler:^(NSData *data,NSURLResponse *response,NSError *error1) { -> returning same result for this also

Comment: maybe some extra parameters need to be set in your Http header

Comment: I have tried with all the headers, but it's not working.

Comment: actual error is "Sorry,You are not Authorised"

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by setting the Content-Type header.  Most servers handle POST requests differently depending on the content type, and you aren't setting one.